# C++ scope of variables inside try

Tags: c++, try-catch, stdmap

Consider this code:

```
try {
    const Asdf &a = map1.at(index1);
    const Bsdf &b = map2.at(index2);
} catch(std::out_of_range&) {
    return false;
}
// <code>
std::cout<<a[b[42]]; // May throw std::out_of_range which should not be caught here.
return true;
```

`<code>` uses a and b. I have two options:

- Put `<code>` in the try block
- Take pointers in the try block, dereference them afterwards

The first option is wrong because if `<code>` throws `std::out_of_range` the function will return false, which should only happen if the map lookup fails.

The second option can be a bit ugly:

```
const Asdf *a;
const Bsdf *b;
try {
    a = &map1.at(index1); // What?
    b = &map2.at(index2);
} catch(std::out_of_range&) {
    return false;
}
std::cout << (*a)[(*b)[42]];
return true;
```

Is there a better way? Something like try-except-else in [Python](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_%28programming_language%29) would be nice, but that doesn't exist in C++.

Comment: If `<code>` throws `std::out_of_range` then you should catch it, what's the problem?

Comment: @maroun-maroun I don't want to catch `std::out_of_range` from `<code>`

Comment: Then surround it with inner `try` clause.

Comment: Not sure whether it's nicer than the pointers, but what about `std::reference_wrapper<const Foo>`

Comment: @johannes-schaub-litb `std::reference_wrapper<Foo>` doesn't inherit `operator[]` from `Foo`. This makes it just a bit worse than the second option.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's not necessary to do any exception handling. [`std::map::find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/find), given a key, will give you an iterator. If the element doesn't exist within the map, then `find` will return the `end` iterator (i.e. `map.end()`).

When de-referencing the iterator, you will receive a pair of values. The first being the key and the second being the object.

```
auto aIt = map1.find(index1);
auto bIt = map2.find(index2);

if(aIt == map1.end() || bIt == map2.end())
{
    return false;
}

const Asdf &a = aIt->second;
const Bsdf &b = bIt->second;

std::cout << a[b[42]];

return true;
```

Note that iterators in C++ are defined such that the `begin` iterator is at the start and the `end` iterator is past the last element (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/end), i.e. the range for iterators within a container is: [begin, end).

Answer (score 4):

## Solution 1:

Why include the code in the try catch, embedding it in its own try catch block to make the difference between the two cases?

```
try {
    const Asdf &a = map1.at(index1);
    const Bsdf &b = map2.at(index2);
    try {
        // <code>
        std::cout<<a[b[42]]; // May throw std::out_of_range which should not be caught here.
    } catch (std::out_of_range&) {}
} catch(std::out_of_range&) {
    return false;
}
return true;
```

But of course in this approach you can't forward to the outside of your function an `out_of_range` that would occur in your `<code>`.

## Solution 2:

The other alternative is to simply check existence of the keys using [`map::count()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/count/) without the need for exception catching:

```
if (map1.count(index1)==0 || map2.count(index2)==0) {
    return false; 
}
const Asdf &a = map1.at(index1);
const Bsdf &b = map2.at(index2);
// <code>
std::cout<<a[b[42]]; 
return true;
```

Comment: I want the `std::out_of_range` thrown by `<code>` to leave the function.

Comment: @BaummitAugen but in this case it will be catched again by the outer block.  I'll edit with another proposal.

Comment: @HristoVenev I've added another proposal to address this requirement.

Comment: Option 2 seems wasteful compared to the solution of taking iterators, as it will search the map twice for each key unless the compiler is able to optimize that

Answer (score 3):

One work around is to ensure that map actually does contain the item. It adds to overhead, but is less worse of the many worse ways I know.

```
try{
    map1.at(index1);
    map2.at(index2);
}catch(std::out_of_range&){
    return false;
}
const Asdf &a=map1.at(index1);
const Bsdf &b=map2.at(index2);
```

Or if written in a little better way (Sorry no performance gain, only readability) unless you want to sacrifice the `const`ness of references.

```
if(map1.find(index1) == map1.end() || map2.find(index2) == map2.end()) return false;
const Asdf &a=map1.at(index1);
const Bsdf &b=map2.at(index2);
```

You can also use [std::map::const_iterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) without the need of try-catch block.

```
std::map::const_iterator a = map1.find(index1);
if(a == map1.end()) return false;
std::map::const_iterator b = map1.find(index2);
if(b == map2.end()) return false;
```

Do whatever with read-only `a->second` and `b->second`.

Comment: That's a bit slower. Not something I would do. It's also about as long as the second option. I could convert the pointers to references after the try-catch.

Answer (score 3):

I like [Miguel's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29730253/3374591) the best, becuase it doesn't involve exception handling (when it is not called for).

But aside from that, here's another option (which I like for being short and keeping the low `map` operations count):

```
bool retval = false;

try{
    const Asdf &a=map1.at(index1);
    const Bsdf &b=map2.at(index2);
    retval = true;
    std::cout<<a[b[42]];
}catch(std::out_of_range&){
    return reval;
}

// more code?    

return reval;
```

Answer (score 3):

An unconventional solution is to exploit the capturing of lambdas to extend the scope of the reference variables beyond the scope of the block. Since the objects referred by the references is valid beyond the scope block, the captured references aren't stale when used later as long as the map object remains in scope.

As an example

```
#include <functional>
#include <vector>
int main()
{
    std::vector<std::vector< int > > map1 = { { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 },
                                                { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 },
                                                { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 },
                                                { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 },
                                                { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 } };

    std::function<int()> fn;
    try{
        const auto &a = map1.at(1);
        const auto &b = map1.at(2);
        fn = [&]() {return a[b[1]]; };
    }
    catch (std::out_of_range&){
        return false;
    }
    fn(); // Any exception thrown here would be caught separately from the above try catch block
}
```